# How can I make Ruby automatically retry a command multiple times?

Tags: ruby, git

Currently our application run fails sometimes, because our Gitserver is very irreliable.

```
begin
  repository = Git.clone(remote_repo,deploy_script_root, { })
...
rescue Exception => e
  log.error e
  raise "Could not export deploy scripts: #{e.message}"
end
```

error: Failed connect to gitserver:80; Operation now in progress while accessing http://gitserver

I was wondering how I could make Ruby retry this command multiple times in order not to break our runs.

Answer (score 5):

use `retry`

```
begin
  retries ||= 0
  repository = Git.clone(remote_repo,deploy_script_root, { })
...
rescue Exception => e
  log.error e
  retries += 1
  retry if (retries <= 5)
  raise "Could not export deploy scripts: #{e.message}"
end
```

Comment: Perhaps add a `sleep` call too before retrying?

Answer (score 0):

Ruby actually has a `retry` keyword that is used inside of `rescue` to retry a block of code. Try [this article](http://blog.mirthlab.com/2012/05/25/cleanly-retrying-blocks-of-code-after-an-exception-in-ruby/) for a deeper dive into things.

Also, this sounds like a bit of a hack. If there's anything you can do to fix the server that would ultimately be better than putting a hack into your code, when the root of the problem seems to be that the git server is unreliable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ruby `retry` statement.  `retry` will return control of your program back to the beginning of the enclosing block.  The simple case is this:

```
begin
  repository = Git.clone(remote_repo,deploy_script_root, { })
  # ...
rescue
  retry
end
```

Used this way, this will retry forever, which would not be good for a production environment.  In fact, at this point, the code doesn't even check which error caused the exception, so it's blindly retrying, even if the error is non-recoverable.

You need some control logic to fail after some number of retry attempts have failed, and check that the error is recoverable before attempting to retry.  This will give you a more robust and graceful solution than the simple `retry` example above.

Try this as a starting point:

```
# For more robust support, consider reading these from a config file
MAX_RETRIES = 10
SLEEP_DURATION = 5

# Begin the retryable operation
retry_count = 0
begin
  repository = Git.clone(remote_repo,deploy_script_root, { })
  # ...
rescue Exception => e
  log.error e

  # Check that it's a recoverable error, before trying to recover...
  allow_retry = /Failed connect to gitserver/i.match(e.message)

  if allow_retry && retry_count < MAX_RETRIES
    retry_count += 1
    sleep SLEEP_DURATION
    retry
  end

  raise "Could not export deploy scripts: #{e.message}"
end
```

With code like this, you can control how many times the operation is retried and how long to wait between retries.  And now you know that only recoverable errors are retried, so that you fail quickly when the error should not be retried.